# Access parameter from the Command Class

Tags: symfony, service, parameters

I am adding a new command line.
I would like to have access to the value of a parameter (parameters.yml) in my Class.

I read that i should add this class as a service to have access to the parameter. So

//config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: services.yml }
```

//services.yml

```
services:
  less_css_compiler:
    class: MyVendor\MyBundle\Command\ThemeCommand
    arguments: [%less_compiler%]
```

//parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    less_compiler:     WinLess.exe
```

it is said that normaly the argument is in the constructor of the class but if  I do this :

```
public function __construct($less_compiler) {
    $this->less_compiler = $less_compiler;
}
```

I have a warning saying that the first argument is missing. In the Command mother class there is a name as then unique argument of the constructor but even though I write :

```
 public function __construct($name, $less_compiler) {
 }
```

It does not change anything..

Other possibility is to call the service inside my class :

```
$service = $this->getContainer()->get('less_css_compiler');
```

But how do I get the argument ?

Thank you

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Simple way, let command extend ContainerAwareCommand

```
$this->getContainer()->getParameter('parameter_name');
```

or

You should create seperate service class

```
$service = $this->getContainer()->get('less_css_compiler');
```

//services.yml

```
services:
  less_css_compiler:
    class: MyVendor\MyBundle\Service\LessCompiler
    arguments: [%less_compiler%]
```

In service class, create constructor like above you mentioned

```
public function __construct($less_compiler) {
    $this->less_compiler = $less_compiler;
}
```

Call the service from command class.

Thats it.

**Reason:** You are making command class itself as service, bit command class contructor expects the command name as the first argument.

Comment: is it really clean to create a service just to have access to a parameter in parameters.yml...maybe there is another way then but using a service ?

Comment: of course yes, $this->getContainer()->getParameter('parameter name');

Comment: Note that since version 2.4 is deprecated to extend ContainerAware
@deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use {@see Command} instead

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem when using Symfony 4.4. [This blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-getting-container-parameters-as-a-service) explains it very well.
If you use [autowire](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/autowiring.html) just update your code as below:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class MessageGenerator
{
    private $params;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $parameterValue = $this->params->get('parameter_name');
        // ...
    }
}
```